# Rotate function, in respect to another function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I am working on a piece of code where I am translating some points along a function, for easing an animation. For example, I have a cubic easing function of `f(t) = t^3`. However, I want the easing function to return a ratio of where to adjust the point in relation to a linear ease. So instead of having the cubic function above move from `(0, 0)` to `(1, 1)`, it would move from `(0, 1)` to `(1, 1)`. In other terms, the line `y = x` that intersects the curve at the edges should instead be `y = 1`

So, to put it into pictures, (in case I'm not wording it appropriately) I want to go from this:
[image]

to this (edited graph to show what I'm envisioning):

[image]

Is there a reasonable way to calculate this?

Comment: Do you want an answer for this specific cubic function, or more general functions? Because in general, rotating a function does not result in a function, so you would need some conditions (or allow implicit functions).

Comment: I'm hoping for a general answer. I am working within the conditions where $0 \le t \le 1$

Comment: If there are any constraints on the function (continuous, differentiable, analytic, polynomial, cubic?) then a more explicit answer may be possible. In particular, if $f$ is differentiable and $f'(t)<\frac{1}{f(0)-f(1)}$ for all $t$ then the rotated function is again a function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t)$ be a function defined on the interval $(0,1)$. Then the line segment from $(0,f(0))$ to $(1,f(1))$ should end up as the line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$. First shift everything up/down by $1-f(0)$ so that the line segment starts at the origin $(0,0)$. That is, apply the translation
$$T_1(x,y)=(x,y-f(0)).$$
Next, rotate the plane about the origin so that the other endpoint, which is now at 
$$T_1(1,f(1))=(1,f(1)-f(0)),$$
ends up on the $x$-axis. This can be done by the applying rotation map
$$R(x,y):=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\hphantom{-}\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
=(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta),$$
where $\theta=-\arctan(f(1))$.
Now we can scale the whole picture so that the line segment becomes $1$ long; apply
$$S(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{|\sin\theta+(f(1)-f(0))\cos\theta|},\frac{y}{|\sin\theta+(f(1)-f(0))\cos\theta|}\right).$$
Finally, shift everything up by $1$, which is simply
$$T_2(x,y)=(x,y+1).$$
Putting everything together yields the transformation
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(x,y)&=&(T_2\circ S\circ R\circ T_1)(x,y)\\
&=&\left(\frac{x\cos\theta-(y-f(0))\sin\theta}{|\sin\theta+(f(1)-f(0))\cos\theta|},\frac{x\sin\theta+(y-f(0))\cos\theta}{|\sin\theta+(f(1)-f(0))\cos\theta|}+1\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
This means that if your original function was $y=f(x)$, now your function is given by the implicit equation
$$\frac{x\sin\theta+(y-f(0))\cos\theta}{|\sin\theta+(f(1)-f(0))\cos\theta|}+1=f\left(\frac{x\cos\theta-(y-f(0))\sin\theta}{|\sin\theta+(f(1)-f(0))\cos\theta|}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

So you are doing several operations:

1. You are rotating the figure $-45^\circ$ around the origin
2. You are scaling the result from part 1 by multiplying with $1/\sqrt 2$
3. You are translating the result from part 2 up by $1$

The best way to deal with these is separately. You have an array of $x$ points, originally $x_0=t$, and $y$ points, originally $y_0=t^3$. The rotation means that you need to calculate the arrays $x_1$ and $y_1$ given by
$$x_1=x_0\cos45^\circ+y_0\sin 45^\circ\\y_1=-x_0\sin 45^\circ+y_0\cos 45^\circ$$
Then for scaling along $x$ you have:
$$x_2=\frac{x_1}{\sqrt 2}\\y_2=y_1$$
Finally, moving it up means $$x_3=x_2\\y_3=y_2+1$$

See if this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

$t^3 + (1-t)$ does the trick! It's not a rotation, instead I am just adding the amount that the linear upper bound $t$ is missing to get to $1$. Hope this helps!

Edit: If you wanted something symmetric about $t=\frac{1}{2}$ instead, you could try the quadratic $at(t-1)+1$ where $a>0$.

Comment: But this is a different curve. Since it approaches `(1, 1)` at a different angle it effects the animation. The original curve is bound by the x axis and `x = 1`. This new curve, if rotated to the same position of the original, would cross over `x = 1` and then rebound to the end point. I want a translated function that still respects those bounds.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but in the second option we can choose $a$ so that the angle of approach of the point $(1,1)$ is the same. In your case, $f(t)=t^3$ so $f'(t)=3t^2$ and $f'(1)=3$. In the quadratic, $g(t)=at(t-1)+1$ so $g'(t)=2at-a+1$, and $g'(1)=a+1$. Setting $g'(1)=f'(t)$ I get $a=2$, so $2t(t-1)+1$ should look very similar to your picture, see for instance [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D2x(x-1)%2B1,+y%3Dx%5E3,+from+0+to+1). Is this any good?